# Can I use a TV or Monitor for a larger screen with my Kindle?

Tags: kindle, screens

I have a Kindle Keyboard and a Paperwhite, they both have WiFi and mini USB.  Is there anyway to connect with a TV or computer monitor so I can get a larger screen size, while reading with my Kindle?

Comment: I don't think so. The mini USB port is not for sending display signals. I think only the Fire HD allows you to stream the display to another device.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Although you cannot stream from any Kindle directly (except for the Kindle Fire HD), you can download any of your Kindle books to a PC or laptop and read them using the PC Kindle App, and you would be able to stream that.

Comment: You can stream directly from the Kindle Fire HD via HDMI. But this answer is correct for the other models, including the Paperwhite.

Answer (score 4):

No, unless you completely replace the software on the device. The mini-USB is not capable of connecting to external devices. The software included by Amazon doesn't allow you to remote the screen over WiFi to another device.